# Rendering error message in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to render errors when a form is submitted in correctly. So my form hits the index as from the controller,

```
  def index
    @player_types = squad.player_types
  end
```

Then in the index view,

```
<%= form_tag({:action => :update}, :method => :put) do %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
<table>
        <% @player_types.order(:number).each do |p_type| %>
             ...do something...
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

In the error message I have a simple error check (for now) which fails

```
<% if @player_types.errors.any? %>
```

because of `undefined method 'errors'`

In most of the examples that are there online, errors method is given when you instantiate an object using `new`. However in my case the object initially has the contents to be displayed. Am I doing something wrong here, should I be even using `@player_types` to capture the error ?

EDIT: As suggested in comments, I have looped in the error message

```
<% @player_types.each do |p_type| %>
    <% if @p_type.errors.any? %>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: I am kind of new to this, havent initialized it yet. My motive was to let the index page work fine and then worry about the messages. Is this something I should be doing before?

Comment: Aren't you trying to update many Player objects ? Using one form to do so might be the wrong way to do so then. What's your end goal here ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to update multiple Player object. The goal is http request, show a form, user edits this form, submits it, render the index page back showing the errors in the form else redirect back to index

Comment: I mean what is the full error message that Rails is giving you?

Comment: undefined method `errors' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f701808e118>

Comment: You are looking for errors on a relation instead of an individual object. You might have to gather the errors in a @player_types.each loop

Comment: I see I tried it quickly now i get, undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Can you edit the post with the new code?

Comment: Oops got it! no need for @p_type, but still same error

Comment: well, just use p_type, not @p_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong here:

**1) You need an instance of an ActiveRecord class to have the errors method.**

From your controller code above i assume you have an index method with an array of instances (has_many relation) `squad.player_types`. The `errors` method can only be called on the objects itself (not on the relation) because in general you would have different data per object that can have different errors.

**2) The errors method an empty array if you don't call #save, #update or #valid? on your instance before**

For the errors method to actually contain any errors you have to call some method that runs your validations before. As you used 'put' as your form method I assume you want to update something, so this would be generally done by the update method in a [RESTful approach](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#updating-articles). If you dont care about that you could maybe do that in your index method aswell. Its kind of unclear for me what you trying to acomplish so I can't give you a code example for that

**3) You can only validate your from data before you actually send your from with javascript client-side validations.**

As I already metioned in 2) you need to validate your data at some point. This involves getting some data from your form into the model instance and then calling a method that runs the model validations. The only option to validate a form before sending it is to use client-side HTML5 or [javascript](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) validations. But be careful client-side validation is only a tool for helping the user and will not be enough to enforce your data to be correct.

---

Finnaly I would like to recommend using form libraries like [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) or [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), that are already able to display error messages in a nice way and there are many usage examples you can find online for both of them.